# Android Calender Set Multiple Color For Multiple Dates

Tags: android, calendar

i am working in android app, i want to set color for date in calendar.

For example i want to show green color for all presented dates, and i want to show red color for all absent dates in calendar.

How to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: what have you done so far, share some codes in question for us to get the context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found [library](https://github.com/SpongeBobSun/mCalendarView?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=2420) to mark multiple dates with multiple color.

```
ExpCalendarView calendarView = (ExpCalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendar_exp);
    calendarView.travelTo(new DateData(2018, 12, 25));

    calendarView.markDate(
            new DateData(2018, 12, 25).setMarkStyle(new MarkStyle(MarkStyle.BACKGROUND, Color.GREEN)));
    calendarView.markDate(
            new DateData(2018, 12, 26).setMarkStyle(new MarkStyle(MarkStyle.BACKGROUND, Color.YELLOW)));
```